# Product of two variables: variance of the glm coefficients

Tags: generalized-linear-model

If we have two stochastic variables *X* and *Y*, and we assume independence (they are actually not). We would like to know the product of X and Y, and we get:

$E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$

We proceed with GLM analysis of both *X* and *Y*, both regressed on a covariate $z$ and obtain a set of coefficients (using for example R):

For *X*:  $\beta_{11}$ and $\beta_{12}$

For *Y*:  $\beta_{21}$ and $\beta_{22}$

R also provides us with standard deviations for $\beta_{12}$ and $\beta_{22}$, namely $\sigma_{12}$ and $\sigma_{22}$, respectively.

We thus get: $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]=\exp{[\beta_{11}+\beta_{21} + (\beta_{12}+\beta_{22})z]}$

In my practice of finding confidence intervals for the sum of the coefficients (beta's) of equal covariates in *X* and *Y* I have done the following:
$\sigma=\sqrt{\sigma_{12}^2+\sigma_{22}^2}$.

But now I wonder if this is correct?

EDIT: clarified notation.

Comment: Are you regressing $X$ and $Y$ on a similar variable, such as $Z$? Or are they upon different variables $U$ and $V$, or on each other $E[Y|X] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$ and $E[Z|X,Y] = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 X + \gamma_2 Y$. Clarify your notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to obtaining confidence intervals for sums of coefficients is wrong. You have not taken account of covariance. It is a basic math fact that 
$$\mbox{Var}(X + Y) = \mbox{Var}(X) + \mbox{Var}(Y) + 2\mbox{Cov}(X, y).$$

Obtaining covariance of two parameters in R requires use of the `vcov` function which returns a variance-covariance matrix for regression coefficients.

The variance of the product is more complicated since expectation is only a linear operator. You can approximate variance of products using the $\delta$ method. Since $f(X, Y) = XY$, $\nabla f (X, Y) = [Y, X]$, and so:

$\mbox{Var}(XY) \approx [E[Y], E[X]] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \sigma^2_x & \sigma_{xy} \\ 
\sigma_{xy}  & \sigma^2_y \\ \end{array} \right] [E[Y], E[X]]^T
$

However, computationally an exact fit is obtained by simply using the bootstrap. It's easy and fast on virtually any computer.

Under the rare assumption of independence, it is true as you said, the product of the expectation is the expectation of the product. It also applies to higher moments:

$$ E[Y^2X^2] = E[Y^2]E[X^2]$$

and $$\mbox{Var}(YX) = E[Y^2X^2]  - E[YX]^2 = E[Y]^2 \mbox{Var}(X) + E[X]^2 \mbox{Var}(Y)$$

which is exactly the same as the expression from Delta method setting $\sigma_{xy}$ to 0.

Comment: If we assumed independence of *X* and *Y* their covariance is zero?

Comment: @erosennin why assume when it can only discredit you? When it comes to estimation, it is just as efficient to account for covariance.

Comment: I agree that it only descredits. But if the assumption were true, my method would be correct?

Comment: @Erosennin yes, and I added a note about independence in my answer too.

Comment: Thanks. But your first sentence about my approach being wrong is loud to my ear, considering I explicitly mentioned the independence assumption. But answer is much appreciated.

Comment: On a sidenote: how do you suggest I go about modelling E[XY] when I cannot assume independence? I must model them separately, like I have before, but account for the covariance, as you suggest. This seems too complex for a guy like myself...

Comment: @Erosennin my question is actually formulated in the general case of non-independence. Reiterating: delta method, just vector/matrix multiplication or bootstrap (easiest)

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail to understand. I see you mention to use the delta method, and I read about the multivariate delta method on wikipedia. It gives us the variance of a function *f* of some consistent estimator. Yes, OK, but how do I find E[XY]? And I see you write something about an exact fit and bootstrap without any explanation. I'm afraid it is all over my head. Exact fit of what exactly? I need to make a model for E[XY] using as many regressors as possible, and I'm afraid I cannot see how your answer translates to this. I know this is all me, but now I only see loose ends..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36860/discussion-between-adamo-and-erosennin).